# Get result from multiple tables in single SQL query

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

1. REPORT_API_USAGE
   [image]

2.REPORT_API_PAGES
[image]

I need to fetch `TERMNAME`, `COUNT(TERMNAME)` from `REPORT_API_USAGE` and `COUNT(CTYPE) WHERE CTYPE = 'download'` from REPORT_API_PAGES. Both table has `TERMID` column.

Here is my SQL query. But its not giving any result. Can anyone help me out.

```
SELECT AP.TERMNAME
    ,AP.COUNT(TERMNAME) AS tot
    ,AI.COUNT(CTYPE) AS event
FROM REPORT_API_USAGE AP
INNER JOIN REPORT_API_PAGES AI ON AP.TERMID = AI.TERMID
WHERE AI.CTYPE = 'download'
    AND AP.VOCID = '21'
```

Resultant image

[image]

Mock Up
------------[image]

Comment: `AP.COUNT(TERMNAME) AS tot, AI.COUNT(CTYPE) AS event` should probably be `COUNT(AP.TERMNAME) AS tot, COUNT(AI.CTYPE) AS event`, and you had (before Radu's edit) an extra comma before `FROM`. In other words, your SQL is probably not even executing, just giving an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of your query would be:

```
SELECT AP.TERMNAME
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT AP.TERMID) AS tot
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT AI.CTYPE) AS event
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AI.CTYPE = 'event' THEN AI.CTYPE ELSE NULL END) AS page
FROM REPORT_API_USAGE AP
INNER JOIN REPORT_API_PAGES AI ON AP.TERMID = AI.TERMID
WHERE AI.CTYPE IN ( 'download', 'event' )
    AND AP.VOCID = '21'
GROUP BY AP.TERMNAME
```

Now, I'm not exactly sure this is the exact data you want, you'd need to show us some expected output from your sample data.

Comment: Your code worked. Can i get one more value in the same query as `COUNT(AI.CTYPE) AS page WHERE AI.CTYPE = 'event'`

Comment: @drup I have adjusted the query to also look for rows which have `event` in the `AI.CTYPE` column and return the count of these values in the `page` column of the result.

Comment: @Radu..I posted the result of the query under 'Resultant image'. The count of event and page seems to be wrong. `Face-to-Face Learning` with `TERMID` 24  is related to 1 download and 0 event in `REPORT_API_PAGES` table

Comment: @drup You have 2 entries in `REPORT_API_USAGE` for `Face-to-Face Learning` with `TERMID` 24. That is why it is showing up twice, instead of once. I mentioned that it would be best if you add a sample expected output from your data, then we'd know for sure how to proceed.

Comment: See my mockup. `Face-to-Face Learning` page is viewed 447 times. There are 223 `events` and 93 `file downloads` with reference of `Face-to-Face Learning`. I am saving `Face-to-Face Learning` and its views 447 in `REPORT_API_USAGE` and  223 `events` and 93 `file downloads` in REPORT_API_PAGES table.

Comment: The actual result should be `Face-to-Face Learning  2  0  1`

Comment: `Face-to-Face Learning` has 2 entries in `REPORT_API_USAGE`. So the joint query is happening twice. I think this makes issue. Do i need to split this single query to 2 to get `event` and `download` separately?

Comment: @drup I think this is what you're looking for now. Let me know if it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT AP.TERMNAME, COUNT(1) AS tot, COUNT(1) AS event  
FROM REPORT_API_USAGE AP 
INNER JOIN REPORT_API_PAGES AI ON AP.TERMID = AI.TERMID 
WHERE AI.CTYPE = 'download' AND AP.VOCID = '21'
GROUP BY AP.TERMNAME
```

this will work,

you added AP.COUNT and AI.COUNT but it should be only COUNT